# Как увеличить количество признаков ML?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Я решаю одну задачу ML, когда мне нужно спрогнозировать цену игры. У меня около 60 столбцов с 10 целыми числами и 50 логическими значениями.

Как я могу увеличить количество своих признаков (возможно, использовать некоторые функции, такие как журнал)?

Я использовал Catboost и LGBM Regressor с gridsearch.

Comment: Что такое журнал? И если у вас сложная модель, типа бустинга, то вряд ли вам сильно поможет feature engeneering. Ну и в любом случае абстрактных рецептов не бывает. Покажите данные, покажите код, покажите, какую метрику оптимизируете и каких показателей добились. Делали ли вы вообще какой-то анализ ваших данных (`EDA`)? Просто бросать данные в бустинг как в чёрный ящик, не понимая, что у вас за данные и какую конкретно вы задачу решаете - ну, такое.

Comment: Первое, что Вы должны сделать перед тем как приступать к моделированию - это понять физику/бизнес-модель реального процесса, который собираетесь моделировать. Только после этого можно начать решать, какие признаки и как Вам надо рассчитать.  В компаниях, которые занимаются ML на заказ, существуют либо специальные методисты, которые изучают процесс и доносят его до коллектива, либо заказчик предоставляет сотрудника, который разъясняет DS, что у них за процессы. Если воспринимать это просто как набор чисел, то модель получится (почти процитирую @CrazyElf) "ну, такая" :)